# Tex - XeLateX - biber how to configure?

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, texmaker, biber, texworks

I am quite new to latex and I would like to ask you for help with my bibliography. 
I am using XelateX on TeXworks in Texmaker. I am writing my thesis based on a template for my university. It is said I need to use biber. The preamble says this:

```
   % Bibliography (references)
    \usepackage[backend=biber,
                style=numeric,
                %backref=true,
                abbreviate=true,
                dateabbrev=false,
                alldates=long]{biblatex}
```

I have downloaded it but can't figure how to compile my file with biber. And I am getting the following message in my Texworks: [image]

I did apply the steps from the previous topic:[Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations) but it did not resolve my problem. The warnings I get are the same and I get no bibliography.

What should I do to make it work? 
I appreciate your help. 
Cheers
KK

Edit 1: I compiled my .tex file with XeLateX, then Biber and get the following information:
Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.1 INFO - Logfile is 'Thesis.blg' INFO - Reading 'Thesis.bcf' INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibliography/Bibliography.bib' for section 0 INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8 INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliography/Bibliography.bib' WARN - Entry ASPS does not parse correctly ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\uqkkepa\AppData\Local\Temp\lU5ArF2aqU\Bibliography.bib_5208.utf8, line 1, syntax error: found "2011", expected "," INFO - WARNINGS: 1 INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: I have the exact same problem :)

Comment: does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations?s=1|0.9049

Comment: Thank you Guido. Unfortunately I did not help. Even after configuring the commands BibLateX to :"C:/texlive/2015/bin/biber.exe" % and choosing second option in the quick build command I still get the exact same warnings as in the picture attached before. 
How can I fix it? 
What is the file Thesis(biblatex)? is it the one with BBL file type? ... I did open the BBL file and run with biber then LaTex but did not work. Also the file is empty.

Comment: The error message tells you the problem. There is an error in the definition of entry `ASPS`. Probably a missing comma or mismatching curly brackets or... something else. If you can't find the problem, post the entry but it is usually relatively straightforward once you have the entry key and line number from the error message.

Comment: It was that easy @cfr . Thank you both for help Guido & cfr problem resolved with the use of your suggestions.

Comment: Great! I'll ping @Guido.

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve the empty bibliography problem? Thank you. @Kasia Kępa

Comment: After installing biber and making sure that in the Configure Texmaker everything is done according to example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154788#154788, I run XeLaTex-->Biber-->XeLaTex and everything worked. The problem was that I had space in the names for the references for example: ''ASPS 2013'' had to be changed to ''ASPS2013''. It worked in myy case. @kww